# Where can I listen online to live VOLMET broadcasts?

Tags: weather, radio

Are there sites that stream live [VOLMET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VOLMET) broadcasts? I need to listen to the format but haven't have the time to put together an amateur radio.

Comment: Does it have to be live? There are plenty of recordings on Youtube

Comment: Good to be live, esp when you want to know how to pronounce different airport codes

Comment: The airport names are pronounced in full in a VOLMET (not just their code). As are weather phenomena. Letters and numbers are pronounced exactly as normal (phonetic alphabeat). Still not sure what difference it makes to you if it's a live broadcast or not.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iX_3XT_hQZU

Answer (score 1):

The Globaltuners site will allow you to tune their UK radios (subject to them being online) to the UK VOLMET frequencies if you really wanted. Whether this is technically "legal" or not is for you to decide ... it's not in the UK, but it's not enforced either.